# How can I stop a window from briefly reappearing at its last visible position when going from hidden to visible?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7, directx

I have a non-fullscreen DirectX window displaying video, which I for application purposes need to both move around and sometimes change from hidden/visible programmatically.
When going from hidden to visible the window may sometimes need to be moved to a new position before it is shown.

I hide the window with `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE)`.
When I want to show the window again, at a new position, I first move it with `SetWindowPos` using the new coordinates and `SWP_NOREDRAW` and `SWP_NOZORDER` flags (I don't want to mess with the Z-order).

Then I call `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW)` for the window to appear at the new position. This works fine except for the window briefly appearing at the position where is was last visible before it appears at its new correct position.

I have tried using the alternatives `MoveWindow` (with repaint-option set to false) and `GetWindowPlacement` together with `SetWindowPlacement` (with appropriate flags), buth they give the same result.

How can I force the window to appear at the right position when going from hidden to visible?

Comment: Try harder? `SetWindowPlacement` should work, I think. In the worst case (where it doesn't work) I suggest moving the window off-screen before setting visible, then move it on-screen.

Comment: Do you actually see the video overlay instead of the window frame?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I've tried moving the window off-screen, with and without going to/from visible/hidden, and it didn't work.

HansPassant: Not sure exactly what you mean. What I see is the last video frame visible before the window was hidden. The window itself has no border, controls or buttons etc., only the video.


My best bet at this point is that it's DirectX-related, in how DirectX handles showing/hiding windows.

Comment: @dwaffy: try moving it offscreen immediately before *minimizing*.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Tried, didn't work.

Comment: @dwaffy: i can't see any way that a correct implementation of that couldn't work for the window itself, so in that case consider Hans' suggestion that you're actually seeing the video overlay. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with DirectX video overlay issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not the fault of either the Windows API or DirectX, but a tricky bug in the way the decoder was handled.
Placement of the window and its visibility status is based on a values in frame user-data passed through the video decoder. When the decoder stopped receiving input data, happening when the network connection to the encoder was broken, it would also stop giving callbacks for decoded frames, with data still in its "pipeline". When input data arrived in the decoder again it spit out a few of the "stuck" frames, with user-data which was no longer valid.